# Make a looping div background fade into different colors

Tags: jquery, css, fadein, fadeout

Im trying to make the background of a div change colour 4 or 5 times continuously, but dont really know where to start. I need the timing to be quite precise as i have to also fade images at the same time on top of the background colour.

Whats the best way to do this? jQuery or css?

Thanks

**EDIT**
I have been able to make the background property change color using CSS animation and keyframes like so:

```
<div class="fading"></div>

.fading {
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    background: black;
    animation: fading 30s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: fading 30s infinite;
    border-radius:5px;
}
@keyframes fading {
    0%   { background: black; }
    33%  { background: red; }
    66%  { background: blue; }
    100% { background: black; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fading {
    0%   { background: black; }
    33%  { background: red; }
    66%  { background: blue; }
    100% { background: black; }
}
```

However im not sure whether this will keep the same time as jquery would, which ill be using to fade in and out images??

Also im worried about what will happen on older browsers are there any fail safes i should be looking at using?

Comment: You could use both, CSS3 transition or animation for modern browsers or jQuery with plugin as jQuery color for older browsers as IE8. Of course, using CSS3 would be more fluid but i think your users shouldn't notice any difference

Comment: Please post the HTML that you have and describe exactly what should happen in what order. If you have made attempts (which you should have) please post those.

Comment: *"i have to also fade images at the same time on top of the background colour"* what you're asking is unclear. Will this image cover the background? In which case why set a background colour? Is the image opaque, does it have transparency? Is it smaller than the element it's in that has the coloured background?

Comment: Sorry @Popnoddles yes the image will be smaller then the element. The background will cover a majority of the window with the image fading in the middle thanks

Comment: Why not fade the image as well as part of the keyframe animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timings should remain the same. Here I've included the fading image without jQuery. Given the code, I don't think you really need help doing this, but to answer the question, for it to work for older browsers as well though, jQuery may be a better option.

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/dP8fL/1/ (time changed to 10s for less waiting to check it works)

```
<div class="fading">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTl7V8rHy90EMd_IYWwbiucARcCPDHnwBkoB7T3ZJjDdqauT-j3eQ" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fading {
    height:200px;
    width:100%;
    background: black;
    animation: fading 30s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: fading 30s infinite;
    border-radius:5px;
}
.fading img{
    width:100px;
    animation: opacityfading 30s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: opacityfading 30s infinite;
    margin:30px;
}
@keyframes fading {
    0%   { background: black; }
    33%  { background: red; }
    66%  { background: blue; }
    100% { background: black; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fading {
    0%   { background: black; }
    33%  { background: red; }
    66%  { background: blue; }
    100% { background: black; }
}
@keyframes opacityfading {
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    33%  { opacity: 1; }
    66%  { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes opacityfading {
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    33%  { opacity: 1; }
    66%  { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! One more question how would i use a different image on each different colour? thanks

Comment: Include several images positioned in the same place, with their animation times different, one might have opacity 0 at 33% and not show again, while another is shown by that time but fades out by 66% etc